# Optimizing sql query which runs slow with large data

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I am using microsoft sql server 2012. Created one query to get detail but it runs slow with large data. Here is the query:

```
SELECT p.BackgroundID,
       sum(od.OrderQuantity) AS number
FROM approval.orderdetail od(nolock)
JOIN project p(nolock) ON od.ProjectID = p.projectid
AND p.BackgroundID IS NOT NULL
WHERE CAST(p.ModifiedDateUTC AS DATE) BETWEEN @startDate AND @endDate
  AND EXISTS
    (SELECT backgroundid
     FROM background b
     WHERE b.BackgroundID = p.BackgroundID
       AND (@isActive = 2
            OR b.IsActive = @isActive)
       AND (@filtertype = 0
            OR ((@filtertype IN (3, 5, 7, 8)
                 AND b.licenseid IS NULL
                 AND b.IsAR = 0)
                OR (@filtertype IN (1, 4, 5)
                    AND b.IsAR = 1)
                OR (@filtertype IN (2, 4, 6)
                    AND b.IsLicensed = 1))))
GROUP BY p.BackgroundID
```

Can anyone help me to optimize query? Any suggestions to optimize performance.

Currently when i run this query first time with large data it tooks almost 1 min and then when i run again it tooks only 3 seconds.

Here is execution plan:
[Execution Plan](https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=Syupdn-44)

Comment: have you looked into the query execution plan?   Do you have indexes on the tables you are using?  Is ModifiedDateUTC indexed, is BackgroundID a primary key or indexed?

Comment: *How* do you run the query? Do you use the same parameters in both runs or not? If you do, the speedup is entirely due to the data already being resident in memory when the query runs again. If you don't, things are a lot more subtle.

Comment: @Cato added execution plan. It shows one index suggestion and performance will 40% faster but my one question is is safe to create indexes for each queries because already there is lots of indexes on same table

Comment: Don't paste execution plans as screenshots -- use https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/ .

Comment: @JeroenMostert added execution plan as per your suggestion

Comment: Would you *want* to reuse a query plan with such a query? With clauses like `(@isActive = 2 OR b.IsActive = @isActive)` and `(@filtertype = 0 OR ...` the query is more like a catch-all query. If this is an SP then the stored execution plan could be useless for the next set of parameters.

Comment: @Larnu this query is used in SP. I want all the filters. Is there any thing which i can optimize in query. Or query looks good?

Comment: Personally, I'd want to consider using `OPTION (RECOMPILE)` with a query like that. The Execution plan you've linked however does suggest 2 indexes; which would make sense as there's 2 scans in your query plan. Although following the advice isn't always a good idea, have you tried those indexes anyway? What indexes do your tables already have?

Comment: put option(recompile) on your query to avoid the potential 'catch all' issue.  Make sure you add the suggested index.  You may be able to find further beneficial indexes, they may become apparent after you add the suggested index.  Your second run speed-up is likely to be due to cached data - you can purge cached data with commands to investigate this.

Comment: will try your suggestions

Comment: Slight detour but something you should read before you continue splattering NOLOCK everywhere. https://blogs.sentryone.com/aaronbertrand/bad-habits-nolock-everywhere/

Answer (score 0):

It runs faster second time you execute it, because the engine can reuse a plan for this query that was created first time you ran it. So now it should stay this way. 
If you're still not satisfied, please include execution plan in your question. I would suggest to remove `CAST` from ModifiedDateUTC - the result should be the same, but it prevents using an index on this field, if it exists.

Comment: added execution plan. It shows one index suggestion and performance will 40% faster but my one question is is safe to create indexes for each queries because already there is lots of indexes on same table

Comment: i am not sure if the performance comes from the reused plan as you say or if it is mainly because the database loaded the data into memory, so the loading from the disk can be skipped.

Comment: Try refactoring the `WHERE` clause expression to `WHERE p.ModifiedDateUTC AS DATE >= @startDate AND p.ModifiedDateUTC < DATEADD(day, 1, @endDate)`. This will allow an index keys on `ModifiedDateUTC` to be used efficiently, assuming ones exists.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT p.BackgroundID,
       sum(od.OrderQuantity) AS number
FROM approval.orderdetail od(nolock)
JOIN project p(nolock) ON od.ProjectID = p.projectid AND p.BackgroundID IS NOT NULL
JOIN background b ON b.BackgroundID = p.BackgroundID
WHERE 
  (@isActive = 2
            OR b.IsActive = @isActive)
       AND (@filtertype = 0
            OR ((@filtertype IN (3, 5, 7, 8)
                 AND b.licenseid IS NULL
                 AND b.IsAR = 0)
                OR (@filtertype IN (1, 4, 5)
                    AND b.IsAR = 1)
                OR (@filtertype IN (2, 4, 6)
                    AND b.IsLicensed = 1))))
  AND
  CAST(p.ModifiedDateUTC AS DATE) BETWEEN @startDate AND @endDate
GROUP BY p.BackgroundID
```

Try to replay `Exists` clause with `inner join` and re-arrange filters which consider those filter first which has indexes on it.